# Slick show 2 row, 6 items on desktop and 1 row, 1 item on mobile

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Could someone help me figure out why my code isn't working? I'm trying to accomplish 2 rows and 6 items on the full width and 1 row with 1 item on mobile.

```
$('.your-class').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
  rows:2,
  slidesPerRow: 3,
    responsive: [{ 
        breakpoint: 500,
        settings: {
            arrows: true,
            infinite: false,
              rows:1,
  slidesPerRow: 1,
            slidesToShow: 1,    
        } 
    }]
});

<div class="your-class">
      <div class="">your content</div>
      <div class="">your content</div>
      <div class="">your content</div>
      <div class="">your content</div>
      <div class="">your content</div>
      <div class="">your content</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Kibs/pen/aNzvBG

thanks

Comment: better to put code here than in another location

Answer (score 6):

You have to change some code in slick.js so you have to use the not minified js version to do that. So, find these two methods in slick.js:

- Slick.prototype.buildRows = function() { ... }
- Slick.prototype.cleanUpRows = function() { ... }

and change the if condition from if(*.options.rows > 1) to if(*.options.rows > 0)

Template:

```
<div class="carousel">
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img src="/images/app.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slick-slide{
  img{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$('.carousel').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesPerRow: 3,
    rows: 2,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 478,
      settings: {
        slidesPerRow: 1,
        rows: 1,
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

that works for me.

Comment: thank you this works, but for me minified js seems different but still can change on if statement to 0

Answer (score 0):

This amend has been merged https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/commit/34612b42641e8fd4250f70666a8da67eb624d002

but WARNING: it has some troubles https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3110

Answer (score 0):

It is broken in the minified version. Download the unminified version from GitHub, and it will work.