# Unwrap my carousel when resize the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){

  var x =  $('.my__list').children();

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length ; i += 2) {

      var windowSize = $(window).width();
      if(windowSize < 500) {
          x.slice(i,i+1).wrapAll('<div class="'+ i +'"></div>');
      }
      if(windowSize > 500) {
          x.slice(i,i+2).wrapAll('<div class="'+ i +'"></div>');
          console.log("test");
      }
  }
});
```

I want to unwrap all my list when the browser's width change. At the moment it only change when the user refresh the browser. Thank you.

I get the source from https://codepen.io/Kibs/pen/aNzvBG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using a row function from slick and some modification inside slick.js. There is some bug from `rows: 2` to `rows: 1` when i used it in responsive settings.

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702923/slick-show-2-row-6-items-on-desktop-and-1-row-1-item-on-mobile) and it works for me:

`Slick.prototype.buildRows = function() { ... }`

`Slick.prototype.cleanUpRows = function() { ... }`

and change the if condition from if(.options.rows > 1) to if(.options.rows > 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can hook this up to the window resize event, or in JQuery `$(window).resize()`:

```
$(function(){
    resizeAndWrap(); // Runs once on page load
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeAndWrap(); // Runs everytime window is resized
    });
});

function resizeAndWrap() {
    var x =  $('.my__list').children();

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length ; i += 2) {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();

        if(windowSize < 500) {
            x.slice(i,i+1).wrapAll('<div class="'+ i +'"></div>');
        }

        if(windowSize > 500) {
            x.slice(i,i+2).wrapAll('<div class="'+ i +'"></div>');
            console.log("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [codepen example with my changes](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQxWZy)

Comment: Hey the codepen example does not work properly. It supposed to show 2 rows and change to 1 row when the browser width is under 500px. I found that slick has row setting. However, Thank you for answer my questions! really appreciate it.